# How to case match a View in scala

Tags: scala, view, pattern-matching

I'm implementing a class to constrain the access on an iterable. Intermediate steps of the sequence (after some map, etc...) is expected to be too big for memory. Thus map (and the likes: scanLeft, reduce, ...) should be lazy.

Internally I use `map(...) = iterable.view.map( ... )`. But it seems, `IterableView.view` is not it-self, which produce useless redirection when calling map multiple times. It is probably not critical, but I'd like to call `.view` only if the iterable is not already a view.

So, how can I case-match a View?

```
class LazyIterable[A](iterable: Iterable[A]){

  def map[B](f: A => B) = {
    val mapped = iterable match {
      case v: View[A] => v              // what should be here?
      case i: Iterable[A] => i.view
    }.map( f ))

    new LazyIterable(mapped)
  }

  def compute() =  iterable.toList

}
```

Note that I don't know what is the inputed Iterable, a concrete Seq (e.g. List, Vector) or a View. And if a View, I don't know on which concrete seq type (e.g. InterableView, SeqView, ...). And I got lost in the class hierarchy of View's & ViewLike's.

Comment: `view` is not a suitable tag here (it refers to DB stuff). What should I put for "virtual" view on transformed concrete data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v: IterableView[A,_]` is probably what you are looking for ...

But I don't think you need any of this to begin with.

I simply don't see what having this wrapper buys you at all. What benefits does writing

```
new LazyIterable(myThing).map(myFunc).compute
```

have over

```
myThing.view.map(myFunc).toList
```

Comment: So `IterableView[A,_]` is a parent of all view type and a subclass of `Iterable[A]`?

Comment: Note about the usefulness of LazyIterable: indeed just that is pretty much useless, but I simplified my problem as much as possible here. Actually, the class I am working on is managing other things, such as sorted keys, and is passed and can be constructed in multiple ways. It is quite a central data structure. Passing `Seq[...]` all over the place (which are, or not, views) is not sufficiently safe and explicit.

Comment: Pass views "all over the place" then. They are views, so it's got to be "safe and explicit" by your definition, shouldn't it? ;)

Comment: Better yet, forget views, and use iterators. Now, _that_  actually _is_ explicit.

Comment: Ok, I guess I did not say enough... :-\ View could be safe enough but, the whole "flat" type whould be somehting like `IterableView[(A,B)]` where the Seq[A] is inherent to the whole system and B possibly long & complex and would change though map op. That's not  explicit. Moreover they are special methods associated to this type that is practical to have attached to it: one simple example is zip with another such `IterableView[(A,C])` that share the same Seq[A].
Finally, we might want to change to implementation some day, but less probably/frequently the API

Comment: At first we used Iterator. They were more explicit, but still not enough w.r.t what I wrote above. Also they are mutable, and that's not safe.